# Как вывести знак доллара после значения в Java?

Tags: java, android, currency

У меня такой код:

```
private void displayPrice(int number) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
        priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(number));
    }
```

Сейчас выводит на экран: $34.00 , а мне нужно 34.00 $ - не могу понять как сделать?

Cпасибо за помощь!

Comment: а зачем - выводит в правильном формате, не стоит городить свои стандарты

Answer (score 1):

```
priceTextView.setText(format(number) + "$");
```